# Classify extremum of $2xy+x^2z-2x^2-2y^2+4y-2z^2$ at $(2,2,1)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**Problem**

$f(x,y,z)=2xy+x^2z-2x^2-2y^2+4y-2z^2$ has an extremum at $(2,2,1)$. Classify it.

**Answer**

The book does [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h09xwbx5i6xsb6j/Screenshot%202014-04-20%2011.45.06.png) and tells us it's a saddle.

**Question**

Can I use the Hessian determinant to classify? I have learned that it works when we have 2 variables $f(x,y)$ but I'm not sure it does so in 3 variables $f(x,y,z)$.
See this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMBCN2w_dz8&list=PLE7F8F33E161D1425) at 33:30 or an example/summary [picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jd6enfj622dwf0h/Screenshot%202014-04-20%2011.41.15.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is the same as in two dimensions and indeed the Hessian *matrix* $H$ at the critical point is pivotal, but one needs more than the Hessian *determinant* since one must determine the signs of the three eigenvalues of $H$.

Here, one has
$$
H=2\begin{pmatrix}-1&1&2\\1&-2&0\\2&0&-2\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The characteristic polynomial is
$$
\det(xI-H)=(x+4)((x+3)^2-21),
$$
whose roots are $-4\lt0$, $-3-\sqrt{21}\lt0$ and $\sqrt{21}-3\gt0$. Hence the signature $--+$, which signals a saddle.

Another route, seemingly more direct and actually equivalent, is to rewrite the expansion you link to, namely,
$$
f(2+h,1+k,1+\ell)=
2-h^2-2k^2-2\ell^2+2hk+4h\ell\ldots
$$
plus some higher order terms, as
$$
f(2+h,1+k,1+\ell)=2\color{red}{\mathbf-}(h-k)^2\color{red}{\mathbf-}(k-2\ell)^2\color{blue}{\mathbf+}2\ell^2\ldots
$$
plus some higher order terms,
hence the signature $\color{red}{\mathbf-}\color{red}{\mathbf-}\color{blue}{\mathbf+}$ indeed.

Comment: With 2 variables, I can make a shortcut, and not compute the eigenvalues. I cannot do it with 3, I guess?

Comment: What is the shortcut you have in mind in dimension 2, exactly?

Comment: Look at my question "See this video at 33:30" or the image. (Linear algebra is used to see that those are <=> ways of handling it.)

Comment: Dimension 2 is special because, if the Hessian determinant is negative one knows that the two eigenvalues of the Hessian matrix are real and that one is positive and the other one is negative. Hence the saddle point. No similar test based on a single parameter (be it the Hessian determinant or another one) exists in dimension 3 or higher. For example, the Hessian determinant can be positive and the signs of the eigenvalues be $+++$ (signaling a local minimum) or $--+$ (signaling a saddle point). In dimension 2, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Second_derivative_test).

Comment: But I get my hessian to be (writing the matrix in matlab form) [-2 1 2; 1 -4 0; 2 0 -4].  I went to wiki on hessian, and then concluded I should do (let xy stand for $f''_{xy}$ etc) : [xx xy xz; xy yy yz; xz yz zz] i.e. in the middle of my 3x3 matrix I have $f''_{yy}$ etc.

Comment: Check the off-diagonal coefficients.

Comment: Now I see why I am wrong. I was still in the "quadratic form" kind of thinking that I learned in linear algebra – the 4 should get 4/2=2 in the matrix. But back then I was given the quadratic form; now I am creating it myself. And, as the hessian on wiki says, it's just the partial derivatives. Great.